# Constructing PropertyChangedEventArgs throws winrt::hresult_wrong_thread

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm creating a C++/WinRT console apps and am getting an error creating `PropertyChangedEventArgs` while other types are activated correctly. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.h>

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs args(L"Title");
}
```

The exception is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCDE9BA839 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_wrong_thread at memory location 0x0000002CF310EF48. occurred
```

This is using v2.0.190730.2 of Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT and targeting Windows 10.0.18362.0 running on 10.0.18362.295.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a thread problem.The call to winrt::init_apartment initializes the thread in the Windows Runtime, by default, in a multithreaded apartment. So when you want to use the content of UI,you need to return to UI thread like below.

```
IAsyncAction MyMethod() 
{
    winrt::apartment_context ui_thread;
    co_await ui_thread;
    winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs args{ L"Title" };
}

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
    MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. You are capturing the context of the calling thread, and then immediately resume execution on that thread. The first 2 lines of `MyMethod` are essentially a no-op. You'll need to move onto a UI thread. You can use [`resume_foreground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/resume-foreground), for example, passing in an appropriate `Dispatcher`.

Comment: From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind), we can use apartment_context to switch back to the calling context. In addition, I tried to add resume_foreground in app, but failed.

Comment: I understand that. But you are switching **instantly** back to the calling context. If the original code fails, then so does this, as it doesn't change anything. As I pointed out before, the first two lines of `MyMethod` are a no-op. The behavior is the same, whether those 2 lines are there or not.

Comment: More generally: `winrt::apartment_context ctx;` followed by `co_await ctx;` doesn't do **anything**, unless there is a coroutine suspension point in between.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but I can't use add resume_foreground in app.